# Can I use metric clic per day or click per day hours to evaluate results of AB test

Tags: ab-testing, abtest

Can I use metric to evaluate result: clicks per day/hour or just per day. And which tests can be used for find if there are some statistical results

I have only timestamp for event of click on specific button. Goal of my ab test it's increase amount of clicks on this button.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think here is the right place to ask your question. Maybe you can get a better answer from [stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions) where they discuss these type of questions with more detail.

However, the answer to your question can be both yes and no.

- If you want to increase the click/ day/ hour then your metric is the right metric to measure for AB restuls
- If you want to increase CTR (Click through rate), then you should change your metric.

But based on the goal you have described for your test, I think CTR would be the best metric. Probably, you want to increase the number of click on a certain button. But clicks are dependant on the number of views. Your AB test should be ran on an independent variable. In order to consider the number of views for each button, and make the metric independent, you should go for CTR because it will include both views and clicks and becomes an independent variable which you can use for the test.